# I've been hacked now how do I recover

Tags: network, windows, account-security

So around December 12th my home network got taken over. I had the default password set and never changed the ssid. Anyway now I don't know what to do. I can't access the web interface of my router so I bought a new one but I can't set that up without interference. Even when I disable all of my network drivers I have an external IP show up. I can't do anything without being under the microscope.

Comment: Hire someone.  There're aspects of how a router works that you completely don't understand.  If you have physical access to your router, you could've reset it.

Comment: Thank you I have a time to learn/ and some basic networking class experience. Ive reset both routers multiple times. I have rent-a-wifi overlapping my house too which was used in the beginning. I was originally going to setup a router at a friend's swap em out when I got home but yeah thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

The question is really broad and will most likely be closed as too broad.  Here are some tips:

1. disconnect from the internet
2. turn everything off
3. Borrow a laptop from someone else
4. reset your router back to factory
5. Use the laptop to connect to the reset router and **change the admin user name and password and SSID**
6. Take any computer on your network and boot from a boot disk and start over.  Make sure you have your files backed up.  Google on how to secure your operating system; that's too broad to do here
7. Invest in a good anti-malware program
8. Never use default passwords again
9. At that point, you might consider reconnecting to the internet

There are probably a lot more things you can do, but this should be a good start.